# Symfony redirect all routes matching a host

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a single Symfony website which has 2 domains:

- landing (www.landing.com)
- main domain (www.main.com

I should configure it so that **every request** which matches the landing host (www.landing.com) redirects to the homepage. Requests on the main domain should work as usual.

Is it possible? I tried with this but it redirects only the homepage:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="landing", host="www.landing.com")
 */
public function landingAction()
{
    return $this->render('default/landing.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a listener and check the host of the current page. This way I can even parameterize the host.

This is the complete code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class LandingListener
{
    private $landingPageHost;
    private $router;

    public function __construct($landingPageHost, $router)
    {
        $this->landingPageHost = $landingPageHost;
        $this->router          = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request    = $event->getRequest();
        $host       = $request->getHost();
        $isHomepage = 'homepage' == $request->attributes->get('_route');

        // landing page domain
        if (false !== stripos($host, $this->landingPageHost) && !$isHomepage) {
            $url      = $this->router->generate('homepage');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the service:

```
app.landing_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\LandingListener
    arguments: ['%landing_page_host%', '@router']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could forward the request of www.landing.com to homepage route.

Tested in **Symfony 3.3**

Though not very common, you can also forward to another controller internally with the forward() method. Instead of redirecting the user's browser, this makes an "internal" sub-request and calls the defined controller.

The forward() method returns the Response object that is returned from that controller, just change the host with theirs:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="landing", host="localhost")
 */
public function landingAction() 
{
    // return $this->render('default/landing.html.twig');
    $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:Default:index');
    //further modify the response or return it directly
    return $response;
}

/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) 
{
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```

Even , you can pass arguments to the resulting controller:

```
 $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:Something:fancy', array(
    'name'  => $name,
    'color' => 'green',
))
```

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/controller/forwarding.html

Comment: I would like **all** routes to redirect to the landing when matching a host.